# How To @Tag An User While Publishing A Post Via Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, tags

I need to publish a post on behalf of user from facebook developers registered application. I am not getting exact facebook graph API to feed with tagging specific username in the post. Anyone can help me out?
I am using following facebook graph API to feed on page by page id

```
POST API -https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/{page-id}/feed?access_token={page-access-token}&message=Thanks @username
```

Comment: I found some relevant answer like we can use user id and username of targeted user @[{user_id}:1:{username}] but this is not helpful to tag user using java

Comment: When I post anything  tagged user not getting notification also.